# Is there a way to stop datajoint from asking for username and password when I import it

Tags: datajoint

In Datajoint, you are prompted for username and password. I am creating a readthedocs website with Sphinx and I need the system to not prompt for username and password. How can I turn it off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for asking this question!
There are basically three ways to do this:

- dj.config.save_local(): This will save the entire dj.config as `json` on your project level
- dj.config.save_global(): This will save is on a system level
- System Variables `DJ_HOST`, `DJ_USER`, and `DJ_PASS`: Can be set for once like `export` in terminal or permanently in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zsh_profile` for linux/mac or in your system settings/environment variable settings for windows

Please check [DataJoint Documentation](https://docs.datajoint.org/python/setup/01-Install-and-Connect.html#install-and-connect) for more details

Comment: Example `dj_local_conf.json`: https://github.com/datajoint/workflow-deeplabcut/blob/main/dj_example_local_conf.json
Example saving auto-generation: https://github.com/datajoint/workflow-deeplabcut/blob/main/notebooks/01-Configure.ipynb

Answer (score 1):

DataJoint asks for database credentials only when they are not already provided in the settings dictionary `dj.config`.  These values can be set programmatically, loaded from a configuration file, or loaded from environment variables. These settings are described in the documentation: https://docs.datajoint.org/python/setup/01-Install-and-Connect.html

Comment: Yes, but I am trying to run unit test and I don't want to authenticate to a server.